# EasyPass enrollment for GlobalEntry enrollees: what to do after you change passport?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany, easypass

As we know, people enrolled in US GlobalEntry [can also enroll (for free) in German EasyPass](https://www.cbp.gov/global-entry/other-programs/easypass), so we can use the e-gates in Germany to pass. If anyone cares, the process was straightforward, involved filling up like 10 pages of forms and waiting for 20 minutes while the German Federal Police types this in, and nothing but passport was needed.

Now, I have enrolled in EasyPass last year, but this year I've got a new passport (with different passport number), and I already changed my passport number at GlobalEntry site.

Question: what should I do with EasyPass? Do I need to re-enroll again? Would GlobalEntry automatically notify Germans about this (and thus my new passport work without changes)? Anyone have done that?

Edit: apparently membership in GlobalEntry is not even required for EasyPass registration, so they couldn't notify Germany. Still the question remains: do I need to re-register with another 10 pages, or can I just bring a new passport to Munich Airport Police and have them registered it?

PS. By request:

**Applying for EasyPass**:

- Fill up [this form](http://www.easypass.de/EasyPass/EN/Service/Downloads/Documents/BPOL_110218a_1014_Questionnaire-for-enrolment-EasyPASS-RTP_file.pdf?__blob=publicationFile&v=9), and print it.
- Bring it to one of the EasyPass enrollment centers (FRA, MUC, and a few more airports in Germany). You'll need to find the police station (bundespolizei).
- Give them the form and your passport, wait 20 minutes. You're done.

**Using EasyPass**:

- Go to the e-gate which says "EU/EEA citizens only", and get in line. Ignore weird looks and comments from EU/EEA people, who'd tell you your passport won't work there.
- When it is your turn, go into the gate, and place your passport's open page at the slot (the screen shows the directions, and they're very clear).
- Wait a couple seconds. The gate will show you an image of "immigration with stamp"
- Go to the passport control officer behind the e-gate, and give him/her your passport. The officer will ask usual questions, and stamp it. In my case the officer often didn't have the stamp, so he had to run to another booth to borrow this, so expect this to take an extra minute or two.
- According to Bundespolizei, this should work at any German airport with e-gate, not only those with enrollment centers, but I only tested it in FRA and MUC.
- It will not allow you to use e-gates outside Germany.
- The main advantage is beating the "non-EU nationals" line where you can easily spend 30 minutes or more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having successfully reregistered, I can answer my question now.

The procedure to update your passport information is manual, and exactly the same as for the registration. Which means, you have to come to the Bundespolice station in an airport, and bring a filled up form and your current passport. Your old passport is not needed.

Also the police told me that in a few weeks Germany will open EasyPass for citizens of 15 nationalities (US, UK, Australia and similar) without registration. Which means you'd be able to use EasyPass gates without having to register first.

A side note: when you put your passport into the EasyPass gate scanner, do NOT flatten it out and slide it all the way into the reader like you do with GlobalEntry machines - it won't read. Instead keep it half-open (at 90 degrees), and slide it in until the corner hits the reader body. Then wait, and it will read. If you're getting 'X' with your registered passport, this is the exact reason.